# What MinGw packages do I need to install to use CLion?

Tags: c++, configuration, mingw, clion

I am using CLion to write C++ programs and I am using MinGW.But I have some files missing namely-**Make,C Compiler** and **C++ Compiler** which are **not found**.I am using MinGW Installation Manager to install the packages but I don't know the exact names of the packages I have to install.

What are the names of the packages I need to install to get rid of this error?(I need the specific names that I can get in the MinGW Installation manager.)

I am also getting these error messages-

> "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles"
>
> C:\Users\Lenovo\CLionProjects\untitled
>
> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
>
> CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
>
> CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
>
> CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[image]

Thanks for any help!!

tps://i.stack.imgur.com/SFWFU.png

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Basic Setup" category in the installer, you need to select and install `mingw32-gcc-g++` and `mingw32-make`.

Comment: Thanks I did the steps you mentioned but I am still getting these error messages-"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\Lenovo\CLionProjects\untitled
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool

Comment: (cont.)CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Comment: What should I do now?Btw the make,C compiler and C++ compiler (not found) errors are solved now...

Comment: If you haven't already installed MinGW Base, install that.  After that's installed, delete CMake's cache.  You can either clear the cache by finding and deleting `CMakeCache.txt` or somewhere in the options menu of whatever software you're using (I'm not sure if you're using CMake on its own, or if you're using it as part of CLion).